# how to insert pipe symbol in TeX?

Tags: latex, tex

How to insert pipe symbol `|` in TeX (LaTeX)?

Comment: Try asking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, at tex.stackexchange.com I've got right answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-tex/1775#1775

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pipe symbol may be used directly in the input and will produce the desired output if you use T1 font encoding. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Pipe sign: |
\end{document}
```

See [Special LaTeX characters](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/fonts/symbols/) for such an example *with* its output and more information.

**Update:** since the question has been posted to [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-tex) as well, this answer has been copied there.

Answer (score 19):

In math mode:

`\|` is a double pipe: ||

`\text{\textbar}` is a single pipe: | (requires the `amsmath` package)

Comment: Output is: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \text
                                                  {\textbar }

Answer (score 4):

http://www.math.toronto.edu/mathit/symbols-letter.pdf

`\textpipe` or use something like `\big|` when in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

write: `\textpipe`

Here you have the handbook of latex symbols: [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: simple document fails with error `Undefined control sequence. l.3 \textpipe`

Comment: \textpipe requires loading a package, for instance tipa or t4phonet.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\textbar` will give the pipe symbol.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -3):

use `$|$` and it the document compiles successfully & it is the best way to type  pipe symbol in TeX or Latex.